# Enabling windows 7 to allow bluetooth file transfers without confirmation

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have a phone that I am using to transfer file in between my various computer using bluetooth. I can easily push files from my computers onto my phone quickly and easily (computers run windows 7, phone is a Samsung captivate on 2.1), however going the other way (pushing files from my phone to the computer) is not quite so clean. To do this, I always have to set the computer to receive a file whereas my my phone is always set to receive files without confirmation (assuming an authenticated connection) and can only receive a single file at a time.

Is there a way to set windows 7 to allow files to be pushed onto the computer via bluetooth without confirmation? If so, how do i set that? If not, what would be a better alternative for very quickly and easily dumping 1 or 2 files back and forth between my phone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open Bluetooth Manager from Start menu. Then:

Bluetooth Manager > Options > Security > Custom Level... > Display a confirmation message on receiving through File Transfer

[image]