# How do I receive multiple files from a bluetooth phone in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I know how to receive a file via bluetooth in Win7 but the problem is that I can only receive 1 file, then I have to start the bluetooth program again, select receive file, etc... Isn't there anyway to receive a file and then receive another without more confirmation?

Is there any freeware software that I can install to just receive bluetooth files from my phone, without this extra-hassle?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://superuser.com/questions/209946/enabling-windows-7-to-allow-bluetooth-file-transfers-without-confirmation/

Answer (score 1):

Use [BluSoleil](http://www.bluesoleil.com/). It's not freeware, but you can receive multiple files without any permission. Just send them from the phone and they will automatically be stored on the PC.